# How to use in-built pytorch accuracy metric inside a function?

Tags: python, function, loops, machine-learning, pytorch

I am creating a function, enc_evaluation, and want to use the in-built pytorch accuracy metric, BinaryAccuracy() inside this function.

```
#my input data are lists

len(enc_x_test)
222
len(len(enc_y_test)
222

# my model
class LR(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, n_features):
        super(LR, self).__init__()
        self.lr = torch.nn.Linear(n_features, 1)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        out = torch.sigmoid(self.lr(x))
        return out
model = LR(n_features) # n_features =9

# accuracy metric
acc_fn = BinaryAccuracy(threshold=0.5)


# my evaluation function
def enc_evaluation(model, enc_x_test, y_test):
    t_start = time()    
 
    for enc_x, y in zip(enc_x_test, y_test):
        # encrypted evaluation
        enc_out = model(enc_x)
        # plain comparison
        out = enc_out.decrypt()
        out = torch.tensor(out)
        out = torch.sigmoid(out)
        acc = acc_fn(out, y)
    print(out.shape)
    print(y.shape)
    
    t_end = time()

    return acc


encrypted_accuracy = encrypted_evaluation(eelr, enc_x_test, y_test)
print("encrypted_accuracy:", encrypted_accuracy.item())
Output: 0.0
```

However, with the manually defined accuracy, the output is this:

```
def encrypted_evaluation(model, enc_x_test_f, y_test_f):
    t_start = time()
    
    correct = 0
    for enc_x, y in zip(enc_x_test_f, y_test_f):
        # encrypted evaluation
        enc_out = model(enc_x)
        # plain comparison
        out = enc_out.decrypt()
        out = torch.tensor(out)
        out = torch.sigmoid(out)
        
        if torch.abs(out - y) < 0.5:
            correct += 1
       
    t_end = time()

    return correct / len(x_test_f)


Output: encrypted_accuracy: 0.5630630630630631
```

How can I get the same output with the in-built accuracy function?

I have taken the reproducible code from this tutorial:
(https://github.com/OpenMined/TenSEAL/blob/main/tutorials/Tutorial%201%20-%20Training%20and%20Evaluation%20of%20Logistic%20Regression%20on%20Encrypted%20Data.ipynb)